# getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I tried to connect to phpMyAdmin database but encounter an error **Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known**. Below coding is the one that I currently use.

```
$servername = "http://localhost:8080";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "dbLogin";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
else {
    echo "Connection success!";
}
```

When I run my system, It will still show the message **connection success!** but together with the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace server name from

`$servername = "http://localhost:8080";`

to

```
$servername = "localhost";
```

Comment: Hello, actually at first I am using the `localhost` but since my port is `8080` so it unable to connect. I used `localhost:8080` also and able to connect but still appear the same error as above.

Comment: @EatenTaik : try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: If you serve your page on :8080, that doesn't mean mysqli uses :8080, probably it uses the default port. You can check by doing a `grep -r mysqli` in your `/etc/php` dir (assuming you're not using windows) and check the mysqli default port there. If it's standard port, you don't need to add it as the 5th param, and just use `$servername = "localhost";`.

Comment: also your if and else conditions are misleading. `if ($conn->connect_error) {  echo "connection success!"; } ` if the connection has error then why have you passed this statement??

Comment: I've just improved my question. I'll try using the `127.0.0.1` first.

Comment: @prakashtank thank you that I realized my mistake, first is the wrong format that you've mentioned and I already change my `$servername` to `localhost`